# Excel displays #Value! when regional setting changed to non-english

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, cultureinfo

I just came cross an issue where Excel would display `#Value!` when regional setting was set to non-English format. (Control Panel-> Region and Language-> Pick Non-English Format from the list)

It's fine if user selects English. All the UDF results will come through and get displayed correctly in the cells. It just wouldn't work for non-English ones.

I have had a look at some of possible solutions online, like these ones: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320369 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa168494(v=office.11).aspx

So I did what's suggested, but still no luck. Excel always gives me `#Value!`. Has anyone here had similar issue like this before? Any better solutions? Thanks.

Comment: What is the formula that results in #Value!?

Comment: I am using custom function, and it looks like =MyFunc(param1, param2). param1 is the id number, pram2 is the cell reference, e.g. A1. So 1 of possible formula examples can be, =MyFunc(1, A1)

Comment: Without knowing the actual code that MyFunc is calling, I doubt that we will be able to answer this question!

Comment: Do you use any date variable in your funtion?

Answer (score 0):

change commas `,` in your formulas to semicolons `;` - or whatever `List separator` is specified in your *Region and Language > Additional settings*...