# How to single out unique records in the whole spreadsheet?

Tags: excel

In EXCEL 2010 I have 2 columns which contain email addresses. I need to find those which are present in the entire spreadsheet (in both columns) only once and single them out, meaning if one record is present in column 1 and 2 then delete both records leaving only those which never appeared more than once. Any ideas ?

Comment: Start by putting them in one column and sorting.

Comment: What Marc says, then assuming email addresses are in column A1-100, the formula for cell b2 is `=if(b1=b2,1,"")` , the drag b2 down to b100. Any place you have 1 is a duplicate email address

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### PREPROCESSING

Put them all in the same column.  Use `LOWER()` if necessary to make sure they're all the same case.  Use `TRIM()` if necessary to remove extra spaces.  Sort them (not necessary with `COUNTIF()`, but will make spot-checking easy).

### MAIN PROCESSING

Let's say your email addresses are in column A, from `A2:A1000`.

In cell B2, enter this formula:

```
COUNTIF($A$2:$A$1000,A2)
```

This will produce the count of each each time the email address in `A2` appears in the column.  Copy that down column B.

Use Excel's Filter feature to filter your list for those that have exactly `1` in column B.

Answer (score -1):

=IF(COUNTIF($A:$B;A1)=1;A1;"not unique")

If your e-mail addresses are in column 1 and 2, try this formula in column 3

Comment: You're putting semi-colons in the formula, and what about checking email addresses that are unique in column B and don't appear in column A?

Comment: I think that semi-colons are the correct symbol for some regional settings - see the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9527024/53614)

Comment: Okay, @barrowc. I had considered that possibility, so I shouldn't have been so quick to call that wrong. Thank you.